# Applying Checkbox Styles in Android PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I am writing an application that SDK 10+.  I would like all of my check boxes in my Activities as well as my PreferenceActivity to look the same.  I created a Theme that has a Theme.Black parent.  I created a child style of android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox and set the android:checkboxStyle to that child theme.  I have applied my theme across the entire app in the application manifest element with:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

When I look at the main Activity, the check box style has been applied as expected, but the checkbox in the PreferenceActivity does not have the style.  My questions are:

- Is it possible to style minor parts of preferences without having to specify an entire new layout for each one?
- More generally, I would like to do this for other controls that show up in the preferences, like toggles or switches.  Is that possible? (My guess is that the solution to one will pretty much be able to be applied to those particular issues as well)

I know there is an issue for nested preferences, but this question is applicable to Preferences at the top level.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I have been banging my head against a wall on this one for a couple hours now...

Here is what I have so far:

prefs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="checkbox1"
        android:summary="This is a themed checkbox preference"
        android:title="Checkbox 1" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

ThemedPreferenceActivity.java

```
public class ThemedPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/AppTheme.Preference.Checkbox" />


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

}
```

style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">    
        <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/AppTheme.Preference.Checkbox</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Preference.Checkbox" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/pref_checkbox</item>
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

pref_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue was with the line:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Preference.Checkbox" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/pref_checkbox</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item> <---- RIGHT HERE
</style>
```

Looks like specifying that was causing the check box to misbehave.  Turns out that I didn't need that anyway (and in fact, realized I would do it in the "ListView" style anyway if I wanted it) so, problem solved.